# How do I use std::vector::emplace_back with vector<vector<int>>?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector, emplace

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> res;
res.emplace_back({1,2}); // change to res.push_back({1,2}); would work
```

This gives me the error:

```
main.cpp:61:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<int> >::emplace_back(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
main.cpp:61:25: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/vector:70:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/random.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/random:50,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/algorithm:63,
                 from miscalgoc.hpp:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/vector.tcc:92:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {}; _Tp = std::vector<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<int> >]
```

How do I make this work? Also, why is an allocator needed here?

Comment: what is your practical problem with using `push_back` instead of `emplace_back`?  What is the name and version of your compiler and standard library you are using?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The problem is that function template arguments doesn't deduce `std::initializer_list` from a braced-init-list (like `{ 1, 2 }`).

Example:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <type_traits>


template<typename T>
void func(T arg) {
}


int main() {
    auto init_list = {1, 2};    // This works because of a special rule
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(init_list), std::initializer_list<int>>::value, "not same");

    func(std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2});     // Ok. Has explicit type.

    func({1, 2});   // This doesn't because there's no rule for function
                    //      template argument to deduce std::initializer_list
                    //      in this form.
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73acdf12e3a52815)

[`std::vector::emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) is a function template with its arguments being deduced. So passing it `{1, 2}` will not work because it couldn't deduce it. Putting an explicit type to it

```
res.emplace_back(std::initializer_list<int>{1,2});
```

would make it work.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef151ed35da1e4d0)

Answer (score 6):

@Mark's answer is pretty correct. Now let's consider a more practical case. After some proper operations, you've collected some data with `vector<int>`, and feel like pushing it into `vector<vector<int>>`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> res;

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    //
    // do something
    //
    std::vector<int> v(10000, 0);  // data acquired
    res.push_back(v);
}
```

It's not like assigning values you already know. Utilizing `std::initializer_list` is probably no longer a solution. In such cases, you may use `std::move` (along with either `emplace_back` or `push_back` is acceptable)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    std::vector<int> v(10000, 0);  // will become empty afterward
    res.emplace_back(std::move(v));  // can be replaced by 
                                     // res.push_back(std::move(v));
}
```

The performance is more or less improved. You can still be benefited from the concept of [xvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#xvalue) move-insertion, constructing objects by move-constructor rather than copying.

**UPDATE**

The [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50227213/does-stdvector-push-backstdmovefoo-make-sense) that `res.push_back(move(v))` works is because they [overload](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) the method `std::vector::push_back(value_type&& val)` after C++11. It is made to support rvalue reference deliberately.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/) for `vector::emplace_back`.  `emplace_back` tries to create a new element in your vector, by calling the constructor for the new element with the arguments passed in.  So basially, when you call `emplace_back({1,2})`, it tries to pass `{1,2}` in to a constructor, but since `res` is a vector of vectors of ints, it's looking at vector constructors, none of which can take a brace-enclosed initializer list.

Also, take a look at the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) for `vector::push_back`.  When `push_back` is called, it creates a default object (in this case, a vector of ints) and copies the values into it.  I would guess that the reason that `push_back({1,2})` works is that the brace-enclosed initializer list creates a value-type, which `push_back` accepts.

Comment: push_back doesn't have this problem though.

Answer (score 1):

Though the question is well answered at the moment, I would like to elaborate on exactly why `push_back` works in this case.

From [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) we see that

> std::initializer_list object is automatically constructed when:
>
> 1. a braced-init-list is used to list-initialize an object, where the
>    corresponding constructor accepts an std::initializer_list
>    parameter,
> 2. a braced-init-list is used as the right operand of
>    assignment or as a function call argument, and the corresponding
>    assignment operator/function accepts an std::initializer_list
>    parameter,
> 3. a braced-init-list is bound to auto, including in a
>    ranged for loop.

3. is not our case.

`bush_back` per se does not accept `initializer_list`, but it accepts `T`. `T` in our case is `std::vector<int>`. So 2. also does not fit.

[This list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) of ways to `list initialize` mentions this one, among others:

> function ({ arg1, arg2, ... })

So, putting everything together, you call `push_back` that accepts `std::vector<int>` with `braced-init-list`. `std::vector` can be `list-initialized` with it, so the vector is constructed and passed to `push_back` (well, reference to it).

`emplace_back` does not work with `braced-init-list` as it is not accepting arguments of type `T` (`std::vector<int>` in our case).

You can try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

struct V {
    int i;
    int j;

    V(int i, int j) {
        std::cout << "i j constructor\n";
    }

    V(std::initializer_list<int> il) {
        std::cout << "init list constructor\n";
    }
};

void
test_f(const V &v) {
    std::cout << "test_f called\n";
}

int main(void) {
    test_f( {1, 2, 3} );
    return 0;
}
```

The output would be:

```
init list constructor
test_f called
```

Answer (score -1):

vector<vector > res;

res.emplace_back({1,2});

Default type detection and conversion happens only once. It does not work twice in it's use cases.  For this to work you need two deductions.

1. {1,2} ->  deduce that the container is an initializer_list of Integers.
2. res.emplace_back( any_initializer_list_of_ints )  -> here since the member element type is known to be vector of integers AND the initializer list of integers can be used to construct a vector of integers, so the initializer_list would need to be converted to vector.

The compilers don't deduce and convert it twice at the same spot. So this will never work.