# C++ How can we insert std::set inside std::vector<std::unordered_set>

Tags: c++

If we have

```
std::set<int > a;
std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>> b;
```

And we went to insert `a` inside `b`

**Method 1: we can do:**

```
std::set<int > a;
std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>> b (a.begin(), a.end());
```

**Method 2, we cannot do this?**

```
std::set<int > a;
std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>> b;
b.insert(a.begin(), a.end());
```

**What does this error means?**

> error C2664:
>   'std::_Vector_iterator,std::equal_to<_Kty>,std::allocator<_Kty>>>>>
>   std::vector,std::equal_to<_Kty>,std::allocator<_Kty>>,std::allocator<_Ty>>::insert(std::_Vector_const_iterator,std::equal_to<_Kty>,std::allocator<_Kty>>>>>,unsigned
>   int,const _Ty &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from
>   'std::_Tree_const_iterator>>'
>   to
>   'std::_Vector_const_iterator,std::equal_to<_Kty>,std::allocator<_Kty>>>>>'
>   IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty,
>   _Alloc>::insert [with _Ty=std::unordered_set, std::equal_to, std::allocator>,
>   _Alloc=std::allocator, std::equal_to, std::allocator>>]" matches the argument list
>               argument types are: (std::_Tree_const_iterator>>,
>   std::_Tree_const_iterator>>)
>               object type is: std::vector, std::equal_to, std::allocator>,
>   std::allocator,
>   std::equal_to, std::allocator>>>

What is the solution if we need to deal with `b` as global `unordered_set`?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're trying to do. What are you expecting the contents of `b` to be?

Comment: The error means that a `set` is not an `unordered_set`...

Comment: What from the error message is unclear in particular for you?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I can't tell if you're sarcastic or serious.

Comment: He is serious, the message says `IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function ...::insert`

Comment: You can't deal with `b` as global `unordered_set`, because it isn't a set.  It is a whole vector of sets.  Did you mean to add the contents of `a` a set already in the vector, e.g. `b[0].insert(...)`?  Or add a new set into the vector, where the contents of the new set come from `a` ?

Comment: @ben-voigt  yes, I want to add a new set into the vector, where the contents of the new set come from a

Comment: @Sandy: Try `b.emplace_back(a.begin(), a.end());`

Answer (score 4):

For method 1, you can to it as below:

```
std::set<int> a{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>> b(1, std::unordered_set<int>(a.begin(), a.end()));
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c872c86ca70ad048)

For method two you can do as:

```
std::set<int> a{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>> b(1);
b[0].insert(a.begin(), a.end());
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccb4a7f2c19703af)

Or alternatively as:

```
std::set<int> a{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>> b;
b.push_back({a.begin(), a.end()});
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79fd069c847db2bc)**

Or alternatively as [@Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt) suggested:

```
  std::set<int> a{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>> b;
  b.emplace_back(a.begin(), a.end());
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75784c3fb6fa00f5)**

Comment: It works a lot like `push_back`, except it avoids making an extra copy of the element being added.

Comment: @BenVoigt I know it takes as input an `rvalue` reference but I'm not sure if it works with initializers.

Comment: It doesn't need to work with initializer lists, all arguments are forwarded.

Comment: @BenVoigt I tried to do it and I'm getting an error http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b90c39609aec6f64, I found this relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391632/how-to-use-stdvectoremplace-back-for-vectorvectorint

Comment: `b.emplace_back(a.begin(), a.end());` works for me.  As I said, all arguments are forwarded, they don't need to be put into an initializer list.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes you are right, I totally forgot about the ranged `emplace_back` :), thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not "ranged".  It's not emplacing multiple elements.  It's emplacing one element, constructed by forwarding all arguments.

Answer (score 2):

For method 2:

No overload of [`vector::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) takes two iterators. Try this instead:

```
b.insert( b.begin(), { a.begin(), a.end() } )
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `b.insert( b.begin(), { a.begin(), a.end() } )` since the `a` iterators define a single element (a set of int) to be inserted?

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm following this overload: `template< class InputIt >
void insert( iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last);`

Comment: You can't do that.  `*first` is an `int`, but the vector doesn't contain `int`, it contains `unordered_set<int>`.