# Does std::vector.push_back(std::move(foo)) make sense?

Tags: c++11, stl, move-semantics

I have come across this in some code (details eliminated for clarity):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> foo;
{
    std::vector<int> bar = {42};
    foo.push_back(std::move(bar)); // Hmmm...
} // Indicate `bar` is no longer needed.
```

The `std::move` looks unnecessary to me, but is it? Is the behaviour any different from just `foo.push_back(bar);`? What if instead of an `int` the element is a class such as [`pcl::PointXYZ`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/structpcl_1_1_point_x_y_z.html) as it is in my actual code?

**UPDATE**: I have altered the code to more explicitly indicate that `bar` is not used after the `std::move`, so there is no illegal access, etc, risk.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Class `vector` has two `push_back` implementations:

```
void push_back( const T& value );
void push_back( T&& value );
```

The first one does copy of the element given.

The second tries to "move" it by calling element's move constructor (if it's defined).

Using `move` forces to pick the second implementation which is supposed to reuse the value rather than just copying one.

In this particular case this is what gonna happen:

1. Vector `bar` is allocated on the stack, but its elements (42) are allocated on the heap.
2. When you call `foo.push_back(...)`, `foo` allocates on the heap a new vector, which is gonna be `bar`s copy. Let's call it `baz` :) Depending on which `push_back` implementation is called the following will happen then:

   - `void push_back( const T& value );`: in this case all `bar`'s elements will be copyed to `baz` as well.
   - `void push_back( T&& value );` in this case `baz` will receive a pointer to `bar`'s elements, so no copy operations are performed. But it is crucial for understanding that `bar` will be deprived of its elemets (now `baz` owns them), so `bar` shoun't be used after `move`.

It isn't that important what kind of the elements are (plain ints or `pcl::PointXYZ`), since only the first vector has allocated the memory for the elements, and the pointer to that memory is the only thing that is copyed during the `move` call.

Comment: So the answer is yes, it is necessary (for suitable values of "necessary") because yes, the behaviour is different as we should save a copy of the memory containing `42`. However, would I be correct in saying that a smart compiler is allowed to and could figure out the optimisation, but `std::move` makes it explicit that the optimisation must take place?

Comment: @KenY-N, yes. Not only it makes it explicit but also makes it work. (The "optimization" wouldn't take place without the `std::move`). You can even use `emplace`. `foo.empace(std::move(bar));`. If the code is *that* simple (no uses of `var` before `push_back`) you can `foo.emplace(std::vector{42})` or even `foo.emplace({42})`.

Comment: @alfC ..and I guess, in most cases the use of `var` might be postponed to point after `emplace`, because `emplace` is meant to return iterator?

Answer (score 1):

> The std::move looks unnecessary to me, but is it?

It depends on your intention.

> Is the behaviour any different from just foo.push_back(bar);?

Yes, `foo.push_back(bar);` will copy `bar` into `foo` (potentially a performance penalty as `std::vector` deals with dynamic allocations). This will also leave `bar` the same and you can use it afterwards.

On the other hand, `foo.push_back(std::move(bar));` makes no copies and reuses the already allocated memory in `bar`. Note that this leaves `bar` in a valid but unspecified state after the move (aka you can't use it unless you reinitialize/reassign it).

> What if instead of an int the element is a class such as pcl::PointXYZ
>   as it is in my actual code?

Move-semantics are only useful for class-types which make use of dynamic allocations (owning pointers). `pcl::PointXYZ` and `int` are no such classes, so it makes no sense to `std::move` an `int` or `std::move` a `pcl::PointXYZ`.

Comment: Note, it's actually an `std::vector` of `int` that I am moving.

Comment: @KenY-N That does not matter. Memory is still allocated for an `int`. Moving a `std::vector<int>` makes sense in that regard.